# Losing data during transfer from one action to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm losing data during transfer from one action to another

What's wrong? I'm doing this:

```
public ActionResult Index(CV model)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult rr()
    {
        CV _cv = new CV();
        _cv.education = new List<Education>();
        _cv.education.Add(new Education()
        {
            Faculty = "sa",
            OnGoing = false,
            Specialization = "asdasd",
            UniversityName = "sulxan",
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            StartDate = DateTime.Now

        });
        return RedirectToAction("Index", _cv);
    }
```

And when I'm debugging to Index parameter model.education.count = 0 instead of 1. In rr action it's 1 with desired values.

My model class is:

```
public class CV
    {

        public List<Education> education { get; set; }
        public Education newEducation { get; set; }
    }

public class Education
    {
        public string UniversityName { get; set; }
        public string Faculty { get; set; }
        public string Specialization { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public bool OnGoing { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure passing this model through GET is the best available option? Why not store it in the session?

Comment: You cannot pass a model containing complex objects or collections using `RedirectToAction()` You need to persist the model somewhere (database/session etc) and get it again in the method your redirecting to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tempdata to store the entity and retrieve the data.use this code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CV model = (CV)TempData["cv"];
    return View();
}

public ActionResult rr()
{
    CV _cv = new CV();
    _cv.education = new List<Education>();
    _cv.education.Add(new Education()
    {
        Faculty = "sa",
        OnGoing = false,
        Specialization = "asdasd",
        UniversityName = "sulxan",
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        StartDate = DateTime.Now

    });
    TempData["cv"] = _cv;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: But if the user refreshed the browser, it will all fail :)

Comment: ya @Stephen. Since he is redirecting, gave this solution. else ViewBag or ViewData would be appropriate.

Comment: I assume your not understanding. `TempData` only lasts one request so if the user refreshes the browser, all the data is lost.

Comment: yup. Tempdata exists only for the next request. Then in that case storing in Session will do the job. But it will be for the entire session which might not be required. If the page refreshable makes sense, then storing in session variable is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer because I'm too much of a noob to comment.

What Stephen Muecke said in his comment is totally correct - and, it's definitely important to persist your data. One other thing to note is that, based on the code you posted, you don't need the RedirectToAction if all you are trying to do is return the model with the view you want:

> return View("Index", _cv);

Of course, without seeing how the rest of your app is built, that could potentially cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tempdata 
like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = TempData["CV "] as CV;
    return View();
}

public ActionResult rr()
{
    CV _cv = new CV();
    _cv.education = new List<Education>();
    _cv.education.Add(new Education()
    {
        Faculty = "sa",
        OnGoing = false,
        Specialization = "asdasd",
        UniversityName = "sulxan",
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        StartDate = DateTime.Now

    });
    TempData["CV"] = _cv;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```